# Xamarin Forms - Url not displaying in Webview

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We are trying to display a URL in a webview in iOS and the page doesn't load, it only goes gray. I unfortunately can't share the Url. but it is an Https Url. It displays Google's website though.

We've added the NSAppTransportSecurity to the info.plist and are allowing ArbitraryLoads. We've also added the domain to NSExceptionDomains.

All the Webviews for iOS are making use of WKWebviews.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Will provide as much info as I can, but as mentioned, I can unfortunately not share the Url.

*Edit: When I added the Url to the Brower on the iOS device, it did load. It just doesn't load on the device

Thank you

Comment: Does this url load in any other browser outside of the project?

Comment: Yes. It loads on Android devices and in a browser

Comment: Hi , first you can check whehter the `WkWebview` work with another url from other place ,such as : whether this url (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats) can be show in iOS device .

Answer (score 2):

If your URL have IP Address then you have to add your URL in NSExceptionDomains.

You can check the **NSExceptionDomains** here : [App Transport Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats)

Please let me know if that might help or you are still facing the issue. Thanks

Comment: THe Url is pointing to an azure hosted web app. One of those azurewebsite.net ones

Comment: Hope you tried to add in NSExceptionDomains .Also please check by adding https to the url and your hosting should be SSL secured.

Comment: We have tried adding exceptionDomains. Link is Https